# "failwith" is no longer allowed?

Tags: compilation, makefile, runtime, ocaml

I have a list of `.ml` to compile defined in my `makefile`, finished by `main/mail.ml`.

I have some `failwith "to do"` as body of some functions in these files. Before, I remember that it raises an error only when the runtime execution requires that function.

Today the compilation of all my `.ml` works fine: `.cmi`, `cmx` and `.o` are all generated. But when I launch the main binary, it does not seem to run first what is in `let ()` of `main.ml`, instead, it seems that it checks first all the files of the list `.ml` in `makefile`, and raises `Fatal error: exception Failure("to do") make: *** [all] Error 2` when it meets the first `faiwith "to do"`.

I find this behavior very odd, could anyone tell me what might be the reason? There is something wrong in my `makefile` or `main.ml`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`failwith` is still allowed ! But this sometimes happens to me aswell.

Usually the problem is that instead of making a *functional* value fail, you are making a *non-functional* value fail, which means that the `failwith` is in fact executed during module initialization. So it is likely that somewhere in your code you wrote :

```
let f = failwith "TODO"
```

where `failwith` gets executed at module initialisation *instead of* :

```
let f x = failwith "TODO"
```

where `failwith` gets executed when the function `f` is actually called with an argument.

Comment: bonus: if you name the argument `_` or `_x`, you avoid any potential "Unused variable `x`" warning.